# Put a label inside each l-geojson component with Vue Leaflet

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, mapping

I need to place a Label inside each Polygon in a map. These polygons are generated by a `v-for` and I wish I could set a `<l-tooltip>` inside these `<l-geojson>` components but it just doesn't work.

```
    <LeafletMap v-if="location"
    class="map"
    :canEdit="canEditMap"
    :zoom="13"
    :center="coordinates"
    :geoFences="geoFences">

      <div v-for="(fence, index) in geoFences" :key="index"
      v-show="!canEditMap">

        <l-geojson
        :geojson="fence.geo_json"
        color="green">
        </l-geojson>

      </div>

    </LeafletMap>
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Are the labels simply ignored, or is there an error? If yes, what's the error?

Comment: The labels are simply ignored. I don't receive any error.